# Effective Java: Understanding Workaround When Implementing Comparable

Tags: java, comparable

In the 2nd edition of `Effective Java`, `Item 12` discusses implementing the `Comparable` interface. There is a statement that I can't quite wrap my head around, and was curious about a concrete example exemplifying the statement.

> If you want to add a value component to a class that implements `Comparable`, don't extend it; write an unrelated class containing an instance of the first class. Then provide a "view" method that returns this instance. This frees you to implement whatever `compareTo` method you like on the second class, while allowing its client to view an instance of the second class as an instance of the first class when needed

So, is the "second class" just a wrapper class containing the "value component" + an instance of the first class? What is the "view" method, a getter? If so, how could the client of this wrapper class "view an instance...as an instance of the first class when needed"?

Comment: Do you understand the problem of extending a `Comparable` class? (Violation of anti-symmetry)

Comment: @AndyTurner two instances could then be return `0` when compared to each other even though they are instances with different fields?

Comment: No, specifically it's that `superclass.compareTo(subclass)` is invoking a different method compared to `subclass.compareTo(superclass)`, and thus they might violate the contract of the `compareTo` method.